# Vim FTP Plugin for IDE-like behavior

Tags: vim

I have gVim (with: NERDTree, minibufexpl). Right now, I can edit files locally with IDE-like feel with NERDTree for a file explorer and minibuf for tabs.

However, I am used to editing files on dummy server I have set up at home. I use Zend Studio to edit files through FTP. Is this feature available in Vim? If so, does it "integrate" well with NERDTree? I would like to browse my FTP directory using NERDTree.

Thank you,
Wenbert

Comment: Which operating system(s) are you using? I would more often use ssh to have a secure session on the remote box and edit the file there or sshfs to have the remote filesystem appear local or, most common, use rsync to keep copies of the files on the two systems in step regardless of where I edit them. These presume a GNU-centric toolset and compatible file systems, though.

Comment: I have Vim on my Mac and would want to edit through FTP from my Mac. The remote FTP server is on Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit files remotely over ftp or sftp or scp or whatnot with vim:

```
vim ftp://user@host/some/file
```

Of course, this also works with tabs. Don't know about minibuf, though.

Unfortunately, the NERDTree plugin does not seem to support this. However, the `:Explore` command plays along just nicely.

Of course, you could simply use [FTPFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPFS) to mount a remote directory and work with that as if it was local storage.

Comment: Mapping the remote directory to my machine as if it was a local storage should work for me. Thanks!